# forcing itunes tags to the file itself

Tags: itunes, media, metadata, tags

How do I make itunes save tagging information to the file itself?

I tagged a file and then loaded it into a different itunes library on a different computer via a NFS share.  The tagging info wasn't present which leads me to believe the tagging info is only stored in the itunes DB.

*Update*

I'm specifically concerned about movies files, so if you RClick -> Get info

Options -> Media Kind (Movies/TV/etc)

Video -> Show/Episode/Season

These tags don't seem to be saved to the file itself, this is lame.

Comment: which tags?  Every time I've tagged a file in itunes the data goes into the file, except for some itunes-specific things like ratings.

Comment: which video file formats are you using? some containers do not support tagging at all: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats

Answer (score 0):

Those are probably iTunes-specific tags, and I'm not sure if there's a place to put them in the files.  However, if both machines are on the same network and both have the latest version of iTunes then you should be able to transfer them.

The latest version of iTunes (9) added the ability to transfer files from one iTunes library to another through [Home Sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3819).

At home I have an iMac that stores all my TV shows and movies, while my laptop stores all my music.  I use Home Sharing to copy files between the two (backup all music to the iMac, and occasionally copy individual TV shows to the laptop).  It works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX, you can tag videos with the free [iDentify2](http://identify2.arrmihardies.com/). On Windows, [MetaX](http://www.danhinsley.com/metax/metax.html) does what you want, but is not free.

Alternatively, you can use iTunes Home Sharing, or make multiple PCs point to a shared iTunes library database (good for single-user usage, avoids maintaining 2 libraries). In both cases, the iTunes client on the other end would see your tags.

Note: The same problem also applies to PDFs.